# Rename PDF based on its content

Tags: vba, pdf

How do I specifically extract the name from a PDF (screenshot as shown below) and rename the PDF as the name? So in this case, I want to extract Daniel Thomas from 'Feedback for Daniel Thomas' and rename my PDF file as it is. I have a total of 180 files; a sample the code I got from online, please help.

```
Sub RenamePDF()
Dim sh As Shape
Dim sDirectory As String
Dim sFile As String
Dim sText As String
Dim lSetting As Long
Dim i As Integer

Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
lSetting = Options.ConfirmConversions
Options.ConfirmConversions = False

sDirectory = "C:\Users\user123\Desktop\"
sFile = Dir(sDirectory & "\" & "*.pdf")
Do While sFile <> ""
    Documents.Open FileName:=sDirectory & "\" & sFile
    For Each sh In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If sh.Type = 6 Then '6 is a grouped shape
            For i = 1 To sh.GroupItems.Count
                If sh.GroupItems(i).Type = 1 Then '1 is a rectangle
                    sText = sh.GroupItems(4).TextFrame.TextRange.Text 'explicitly get 4th rectangle
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next sh
    sText = Left(sText, Len(sText) - 1)
    ActiveDocument.Close False
    Name sDirectory & sFile As sDirectory & Split(sFile, "-")(0) & " - " & sText & ".pdf"
    sFile = Dir
Loop
Options.ConfirmConversions = lSetting
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is highly depending on the content of the PDF. You could try to open the PDF with Word and search for the term `Feedback` and read the remainder of the line. Don't forget to close the file (without saving!) before you rename it.

Comment: But I have 180 files tho. Although, the position of the text are always the same. I just need the name

Comment: If you can do it with one file, you can do it with all files - just loop over all files using the `Dir`-command or a `FileSystemObject` - tons of examples on SO and everywhere.

Comment: the thing is, do you have any idea how do it do? been stuck for a while

Comment: What? To loop over the files? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+loop+files To read a PDF into Word? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open To find text? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find  Where are you stuck?